# Django views returning only one particular field instead of entire model

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-haystack

I am new to Django. I tried to write a view that returns the fields of a foreign key model associated with the search term. Instead of the whole model (foreign key) I am getting only a particular field.

This is the view with the problem:

```
@csrf_exempt
@requires_csrf_token
def search_haystack(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_text = request.POST['search']
        print search_text
    else:
        search_text = ''
    results_list= None

    if str(search_text) != "":
        results_dish = SearchQuerySet().models(dish).filter(content=AutoQuery(request.POST.get("search", "")))
            for result in results_dish:
                print result.resto
                print result.resto.name
                print result.resto.area
            results_list = [{'resto_id':result.resto.id , 'name' :result.resto.name, 'area' :result.resto.area} for result in results_dish]
    else:
        results = None
    print results_list
    print encodeToJsonHaystack(results_list)
    return HttpResponse(encodeToJsonHaystack(results_list), mimetype = "application/json")
```

models:

```
class resto(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField("id", max_length=100, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    area=models.CharField("area", max_length = 100,blank = True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 100,blank = True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table=u'resto'

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.name


class dish(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField("id", max_length=100, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    resto= models.ForeignKey(resto)
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 50,blank = True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table=u'dish'

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.name
```

The line "print result.resto" prints the name of the resto.

print result.resto.name and print result.resto.area does not print anything.

Why is that? What do I need to do to get all the fields of the resto?

search_indexes.py

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from litchee.models import resto
from litchee.models import dish


class restoIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    area = indexes.CharField(model_attr='area')

    def get_model(self):
         return resto

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()


class dishIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    resto = indexes.CharField(model_attr='resto')

    def get_model(self):
        return dish

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all() #Add support for Is Shutdown
```

Comment: Does it have any values? :)

Comment: Yes! result.resto is returning the value result.resto.name should be returning.

Comment: You aren't querying Django models at all here. You're querying a search index, via Haystack. You'll need to at least post your Haystack configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Haystack configuration. Using haystack with Django only required an installation of Haystack and to add this to settings.py

`HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },`

Comment: No, surely you must have created SearchIndex classes to actually index your data.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the question to add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you're not querying Django models, you're querying a search engine via Haystack. What you get back isn't an instance of the model, but . In the search index for the Dish model, `resto` is a CharField, so naturally that's what you get in the search results, rather than a reference to another model.

You should be able to access the actual Django model instance for each result via the [`object` attribute](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchresult_api.html) and from there you can follow the foreign key.

Note that if you're completely new to Django, you might want to forget about Haystack for now until you've properly understood how the actual model API works. You may not actually need it at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm really new to this, can't figure out how exactly (what code) this is to be done i.e. how to use the object attribute. I'll accept this answer as soon as I get it.